# based on the table value i need to joining a table in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I having the three tables

```
 Table1
 1.id
 2.name
 3.address
 4.City
 5.InstituteName

 Table2
 1.collegeId
 2.CollegeName
 3.CollegeAddress

 Table3
 1.Schoolid
 2.SchoolName
 3.SchoolAddress
```

Now i need to show view in html table (MVC 2) in table1 the instituteName is contains a flag if its 0 then its school(table3) if its 1 then College(table2) now my view is

```
 1. id
 2. Name     
 3. SchoolName (OR) CollegeName
 4. School (OR) CollegeAddress
```

how i can do this friends please help me in linq

Comment: Need to know how tables are related. Does Table2 and Table3 have the parent ID? (Table1.Id?)

Comment: No friend i dont have any partent key actully table2 and table3 are master table1 is accesing infomation based on its institute

Comment: you lost me there, can you post your full model definitions?

Comment: So which is the foreign key in table 2 and table 3?

Comment: No foreign Key is there